# Extract domain name with no domain extension in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to extract the domain name only from a cell in Google Sheets. The cell can have either a `.com` or `.co.uk` extension.

They are always presented as naked domains with `www` or `https://`.

*Column A* will contain a list of random URLs that will be displayed as `aol.com` or `amazon.co.uk`.

I have tried the following and many varients, I think essentially this is "remove everything BEFORE the dot" and regex actually uses a dot to perform its duty. Therefore, that is what is perhaps causing a potential conflict.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "(.+).")
```

The result will eventually be piped into a QUERY where the company name is checked.

```
=query(Companies!A2:F,"select A where F contains '"&A2&"'")
```

Comment: That has done it Wiktor, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you may have only `.com` or `.co.uk` at the end of the strings, you may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "^(.+)\.(?:co\.uk|com)$")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxI3Qs/1).

Also, you may remove them at the end with

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A4, "\.(?:co\.uk|com)$", "")
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxI3Qs/2)

You may also consider a bit more generic patterns like

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A4, "^(.+?)(?:\.co)?\.[^.]+$")
=REGEXREPLACE(A4, "(?:\.co)?\.[^.]+$", "")
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.+)` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(.+?)` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (needed in the more generic patterns because the subsequent pattern is optional)
- `\.(?:co\.uk|com)$` - `.` and then `co.uk` or `com` at the end of the string
- `(?:\.co)?\.[^.]+$` - an optional `.co` char sequence and then `.` and 1 or more chars other than a `.` till the end of the string.